# How to establish random connections in omnet++ ned file?

Tags: omnet++

Can anybody please tell me, how to to establish random connections with submodules(i.e.,nodes or peers) in a network. But the connections each submodule has with other submodules should be between 2-5 only. I am not able to find the right keywords to use in "ned" file to do the same. I have tried the below code in ned file but unable to create connections exactly between 2-5. Kindly, please help or suggest.

```
network Tictoc15
parameters:
     double n @prompt("Number of nodes");
types:
    channel Channel extends ned.DelayChannel {
        delay = 100ms;
    }
submodules:
    tic[n]: Txc15{
    gates:
        gate[n];
```

}

```
connections :
for i=0..n-2, for j=i+1..n-1 {
 tic[i].gate++ <--> Channel <--> tic[j].gate++ if intuniform(1,n)>3 && intuniform(1,n)<2;
```

}

Comment: I cannot figure out what does "But the connection should be between 2-5 only." mean? ALso the "establish connections with random submodules" is unclear.

Comment: @Rudi
Sorry for the grammar. What I mean is, suppose I enter the Number of nodes as a parameter to build a network. Lets say I enter 10, Then each of these node should be randomly connected to atleast 2 and atmost 5 other nodes in the network. I hope I am clear now.